# Rails: :inverse_of and Association extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, inverse

I have the following set-up

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards, :inverse_of => :player do
    def in_hand
      find_all_by_location('hand')
    end
  end
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player, :inverse_of => :cards
end
```

This means the following works:

```
p = Player.find(:first)
c = p.cards[0]
p.score # => 2
c.player.score # => 2
p.score += 1
c.player.score # => 3
c.player.score += 2
p.score # => 5
```

But the following doesn't behave the same way:

```
p = Player.find(:first)
c = p.cards.in_hand[0]
p.score # => 2
c.player.score # => 2
p.score += 1
c.player.score # => 2
c.player.score += 2
p.score # => 3

d = p.cards.in_hand[1]
d.player.score # => 2
```

How can I make the `:inverse_of` relationship extend to the extension methods? (Is this just a bug?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because the "in_hand" method has a query that goes back to the database.

Because of the inverse_of option, the working code knows how to use the objects that are already in memory.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Ok, is there any way to make it work with the "in_hand" method?

Answer (score 7):

I have found a workaround if (as I am) you're willing to give up the SQL optimisation granted by Arel and just do it all in Ruby.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards, :inverse_of => :player do
    def in_hand
      select {|c| c.location == 'hand'}
    end
  end
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player, :inverse_of => :cards
end
```

By writing the extension to filter in Ruby the full results of the association, rather than narrowing down the SQL query, results returned by the extension behave correctly with `:inverse_of`:

```
p = Player.find(:first)
c = p.cards[0]
p.score # => 2
c.player.score # => 2
p.score += 1
c.player.score # => 3
c.player.score += 2
p.score # => 5

d = p.cards.in_hand[0]
d.player.score # => 5
d.player.score += 3
c.player.score # => 8
```