# How can I get the owner of an unsaved HABTM collection proxy in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have two models defined like this, one with a custom validation that checks its parents (owners) for some condition.  It could be any condition on the parent, not just the one I'm using in the example:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :phrases
end

class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

  validate do
    if self.projects.size == 0
      errors.add(:base, "Must have at least one parent project")
    end
  end
end
```

Then, after creating a new project, I'd like to create a new phrase under it:

```
project = Project.create!(:name => "My Project")
phrase = project.phrases.create!(:value => "My phrase")
```

When validations run, no rows have actually been created in the join table, and `phrase` is unsaved.  The validation fails as we expect it should.

The question then is this: How can I access the parent `Project` instance inside the `validate` block?  Since I'm calling `project.phrases.create!` I'm explicitly saying "create a new `Phrase` as a child of this specific parent `Project`".  Is there any way to access it?  ActiveRecord associations provide an `owner` method, but it's not available inside `validate` as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use inverse_of, it helps know the objects that are already in memory.

http://gsusmonzon.blogspot.in/2011/09/rails-power-of-inverseof.html

**EDIT:**
Similar question on SO:
[Rails: :inverse_of and Association extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146278/rails-inverse-of-and-association-extensions)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like `:inverse_of` doesn't work with HABTM associations.  I tried adding it to both calls to `has_and_belongs_to_many` and got `Unknown key: inverse_of (ArgumentError)`

Comment: in Rails 4.1 it works ok, I have this in the model Groups "has_and_belongs_to_many :users, inverse_of: :groups"